# Super key not working on external keyboard

Tags: keyboard

I am using an external keyboard on my laptop and the **Super** key doesn't work. The laptop's keyboard works just fine, every key is regularly detected.

I tried using `xinput` to debug this issue. Here you can see the output of `xinput list`, the device I am having issues with is the **Cooler Master Technology Inc. MasterKeys Pro L White**.

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Bluetooth  Mouse                          id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Chicony USB 2.0 Camera: Chicony           id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Cooler Master Technology Inc. MasterKeys Pro L White  id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Cooler Master Technology Inc. MasterKeys Pro L White  id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

I tried running `xinput test-xi2 12` to see if the events from the keyboard where issued. All keys are working except for the super keys. I tested the keyboard with my desktop PC and all keys are working fine.

I am running **Ubuntu 16.04.5** with kernel version **4.13.0-45-generic**, **Unity** as Desktop Environment and **Compiz** as Windows Manager.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Make sure you didn't disable the super key from the keyboard. I have CM Storm Quickfire TK, everything works fine. I can enable gaming mode on the keyboard, and thus disable the super key altogether.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I didn't know about this lock key. Now the super key is working fine.

Comment: same problem here with an Avell notebook.

Comment: Thank you! My Logitech G710+ keyboard apparently has a key like that as well. :)

Comment: My Das Keyboard x50 on Ubuntu had the same thing. I didn't know there was a gaming mode. Pressing FN + PAUSE turned that off and I got my super key back. For me the issue was I couldn't lock the computer with SUPER + L with this active.

Comment: THANK YOU! I have a Logitech G613 and has exactly this problem. Actually I ever experienced this before and fixed it, but then I forgot what the problem was, hehe. Additional keyword: "Windows key/button not working on Ubuntu with Logitech Bluetooth wireless keyboard"